# http to https double redirection found

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301, http-redirect

I am trying to redirect http to https with three options

- http:// to https://
- http://www to https://
- https://www to https://

However, the second option is showing double redirect from `http://www > https://www > https://`

Following is the code I have in .htaccess. Is it fine to have a double redirect?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SInce you have 2 redirection rules. A redirection may happen twice as:

1. Using first rule `http://www.example.com` to `https://www.example.com`
2. Using second rule `https://www.example.com` to `https://example.com`

You can use this single rule to do both in a single `301` redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Make sure you replace both of your rules with this one and use a new browser for testing to avoid old browser cache.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Anubhava! That was tricky! In fact hosting company told me not to believe third-party apps : )

Comment: Hosting companies tell all kind of stories since they don't really understand these things :)

Comment: Appreciate your swift help, friend! Thanks, again!